# How can I create a download link that won't change my browser's URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, download, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this link that a user will click on to download a file …

```
<%= link_to "#{scenario_file.title}", scenario_file_path(scenario_file) %>
```

It links off to this controller method …

```
  def show
    @scenario_file = ScenarioFile.find(params[:id])
    send_data @scenario_file.file_data, filename: "#{@scenario_file.title}", type: @scenario_file.mime_type, :disposition => 'attachment' 
  end
```

My problem is, when someone clicks on the link, the browser URL changes to the link (obviously).  However, is there any way I can rewrite the above link so that the file will download but my browser’s URL won’t change?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `target="_blank"` to link:

```
<%= link_to "#{scenario_file.title}", scenario_file_path(scenario_file), target: '_blank' %>
```

Too you can use html5 [download](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) attribute. The download attribute is triggering a force download.

```
<%= link_to scenario_file.title, scenario_file_path(scenario_file), download: scenario_file.title %>
```

Comment: Hi, Your HTML 5 solution is still causing the URL in the browser to change.